# How is sentencing determined for involuntary manslaughter with multiple victims?

Tags: sentencing, manslaughter

How does sentencing work in cases where someone is found guilty of involuntary manslaughter where there were multiple victims? For example, someone causes a serious construction accident by negligence, which kills multiple people. Is the person given the same sentence as if there was only one victim, or are the sentences added together or is it something in between?

Comment: Sentencing is governed by local law, depending on who has outlawed involuntary manslaughter. You should pick a jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the question of whether the sentences are to run [consecutively or concurrently](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/concurrent-consecutive-sentences-double-punishment.html), and it's part of the sentencing decision.  In many cases, the judge may have the discretion to make this decision based on the circumstances of the crime, the defendant's history, and so on.  Some jurisdictions might have sentencing guidelines to help ensure consistency; in some cases these guidelines might be mandatory, limiting the judge's discretion.

Comment: So even if all deaths are caused by the same single action, the sentences may be run consecutively and is usually at the discretion of the judge. If I understand that correctly.